# I want to filter and parse logs for specific domain in logstash

Tags: filter, logstash, haproxy

I want to parse logs for specific domain(below: abc refers to abc.com) using logstash.This is the filter that i am trying to use inside logstash input:

```
   input {.......}
   filter {
       if [message] =~ "abc" {
           grok {
               match => ["message", .......]
           }
       }
   }
   output {
       elasticsearch{.......}
   }
```

On the above config, i am specifying to filter logs with abc, however, this doesn't seems to be effective, when i see on ES index, I get to see logs getting parsed for all different domains along with abc, which I don't want.

BTW, I am trying to parse HAPROXY logs. I want logs only for specific domains(say abc to be indexed into ES) and ignore everything apart from abc.com

Answer (score 1):

Your entire config is executed for every message that comes in, unless you use conditionals.  The grok{} should only be run for "abc", but your output{} would still be reached.

To keep the other messages from going to elasticsearch, use drop{}:

```
if [message] =~ "abc" {
}
else {
    drop { }
}
```